# tcc: error: undefined symbol 'pthread_create'

Tags: c, linker, tcc

I am trying to compile this with tcc

[image]

and I have these errors

[image]

Before the error it was "Cannot find pthread.h" and I copied 
pthread,pthread_compat,pthread_signal,pthread_time,pthread_unistd  header files from gcc include dir to tcc include dir ! ... and now I have the above errors.. I think is something with linking but I don't know exactly :/

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know about that.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to use thread support from gcc with tcc.

Answer (score 0):

Copying header files from the gcc include dir was neither required nor a good idea; better use tcc option: `-Igcc-include-dir-path`.
Anyway, now you will need to link your program to the pthread library in order complete build. Look in the gcc directory for a file named `pthread.a` or `pthread.lib`, there you have the gcc libraries directory. Then when you get this directory path, add the following options to the tcc command-line: `-Lgcc-library-dir-path -pthread`.